# How do I add Core Data stack to WatchKit app

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, watchkit

How do I add my core data stack (from my iOS app) to my WatchKit app? In my iOS app, the Core Data stack is in my `AppDelegate`, however there is no `AppDelegate` in my WatchKit app. Does this mean I need to create a new `AppDelegate` file for the Watch app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the stack in a singleton. Create a new class make it a singleton so you know you will only ever have one instance.

```
    class CoreDataStack: NSObject {
    // MARK: - Singleton with private init
    static let sharedInstance = CoreDataStack()
    private override init(){
    }
    // add your core data stack here
}
```

Then you can access it from any where in your app by simply

```
 let coreDataStack = CoreDataStack.sharedInstance
//and then you can do things like
let myManagedObjectContext = coreDataStack.managedObjectContext
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I did this. Another question, so can/should I do this in my iOS app? Because I've been passing my managedObjectContext variable around everywhere, as taught by Ray Wenderlich's iOS Apprentice book. I'm guessing it probably doesn't make much of a difference, since you still need to obtain a reference to the `coreDataStack` though.

Comment: I don't see any reason to change your iOS app if you have it working. I think  if your app has loads of view controllers and you are trying to keep track of your Moc instance this just seems a simpler approach also to me it feels wrong to have model code  in the app delegate.